# Discrete Logarithm Variation

Tags: exponentiation, discrete-logarithms

Given a positive integer $x$, is there an efficient method to determine integers $k$, $a$ and $b$ such that $kx+1=a^b$?

Examples:

$x=17$, $15(17)+1=2^8$

$x=13$, $2(13)+1 = 3^3$

$x=12$, $2(12)+1 = 5^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any positive integer $x$, you can have $a = cx + 1$, for any positive integer $c$. Then, for any positive integer $b$, you get the positive integer $k = \frac{(cx+1)^b - 1}{x}$.

If you wish to use other values for $a$, in particular for $a \lt x$, here's how you can do it. Choose any $a$ which is relatively prime to $x$ (i.e., have no factors in common). Then you can choose $b$ to be the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $a$ modulo $x$, or any integral multiple of this (such as [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)). For the special case where $x$ is prime, then by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), you can choose any $a$ not a multiple of $x$, with $b = x - 1$ (or any integral multiple of this) working. Finally, note with any $a$ which works, then this value plus or minus any multiple of $x$ will also work.

Comment: Thanks, what about determining solutions where a is not equal to cx+1, like the examples, does this problem become the discrete logarithm problem?

Comment: @RuanSunkel I thought you might be interested in that, so I added more details in an update. I hope that helps to answer your question more fully.

Comment: Thanks, yes it does. Multiplicative order is the term I was looking for, not discrete logarithm.

Comment: @RuanSunkel You're welcome. I'm glad I could be of help. Knowing the correct term to use is so helpful when communicating with people, doing searches, etc.